# How can i solve the error while 'gcc' linking in Ubuntu 32bit?

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

```
nasm -f elf sample_io.asm
nasm -f elf -d ELE_TYPE asm_io.asm
gcc -o sample_io sample_io.o asm_io.
```

Error message: 
[image]

After downloading two files (asm_io.asm, sample_io.asm),
I tried to link by using 'gcc'
And the 'link error' occurs like the image displayed.
How can I solve this problem? I use Ubuntu 32-bit, nasm.

Comment: Please copy text from the picture and include it in your post. It'll be easier to search for both people who can help you and people who need help with the same problem

Comment: Please add the error message as simple text (with proper formating) instead of an image.

Comment: Try 'F' instead of 'E': `-d ELF_TYPE`

Comment: You need to change `-d ELE_TYPE` to `ELF_TYPE` and you will need to download and compile cdecl.h and driver.c to compile to driver.o as well. Then you have to link to driver.o in addition to asm_io.o. So try this `nasm -f elf -d ELF_TYPE asm_io.asm` `nasm -f elf sample_io.asm` `gcc -c driver.c` and then link it together as an executable with `gcc -o sample_io sample_io.o asm_io.o driver.o`

Comment: You would normally also need `gcc -m32`, but that's already the default on a 32-bit Ubuntu install.  Strange choice in 2018...